# Typing a function whose param is a key in a type, and whose `ReturnType` is the corresponding type for that key

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I'm working in typescript. I have this type:

```
type Mapping = {
    a: number,
    b: string,
    c: CustomType1,
    d: CustomType2
};
```

I want to define a separate type, named `MapFn`. This type defines a function, which accepts any key in `Mapping` as its only parameter, and the return value of `MapFn` is the same as the type mapped to by the given key. So for example consider:

```
const mapFn: MapFn = getMapFnSomehowIdontCare();
const mapFnResult1 = mapFn('c'); // typeof mapFnResult1 should be `CustomType1`
const mapFnResult2 = mapFn('a'); // typeof mapFnResult1 should be `number`
```

Chatgpt says I should try:

```
type MapFn = (key: keyof Mapping) => Mapping[keyof Mapping];
```

But this clearly doesn't work - the known type associated with `key` has no effect on the return value.

How can I define `MapFn` to fulfill these requirements? Is this within scope for typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Oh it was pretty easy:

```
type MapFn<K extends keyof Mapping> = (key: K) => Mapping[K];
```